# Attributes add for subscribers

Tags: php, marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, fuel

code snippet.

```
require('ET_Client.php');
$myclient = new ET_Client();
$NameOfAttributeOne = "ExampleAttributeOne";
$NameOfAttributeTwo = "ExampleAttributeTwo";
$profileAttrOne = array("Name" => $NameOfAttributeOne, "PropertyType"=>"string", "Description"=>"New Attribute from the SDK", "IsRequired"=>"false", "IsViewable"=>"false", "IsEditable"=>"true", "IsSendTime"=>"false");
$profileAttrTwo = array("Name" => $NameOfAttributeTwo, "PropertyType"=>"string", "Description"=>"New Attribute from the SDK", "IsRequired"=>"false", "IsViewable"=>"false", "IsEditable"=>"true", "IsSendTime"=>"false");
$response = $myclient->CreateProfileAttributes(array($profileAttrOne,$profileAttrTwo));
print_r($response);
```

reponse:

```
[StatusCode] => Error
[StatusMessage] => PropertyDefinitionReadOnlyAccess
[OrdinalID] => 0
[ErrorCode] => 67035
```

Comment: I would recommend that you also post this question at [Code@ExactTarget](https://code.exacttarget.com/), since this is largely not related to salesforce as it is currently written.

Comment: @sfdcfox : exacttarget is in scope of this site now too: http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/505/exacttarget-add-to-sf-se-or-spin-up-a-new-se

Comment: @Deepak : It may help if you explain what you're trying to do, and actually ASK a question. While we can try to conclude your question, it helps a lot if you actually ask it.

Comment: @Sdry You're right. I must have missed that meta. Silly me. Regardless, I tried to find an answer (below). ExactTarget does have their own hosted forum with internal experts that help, though. That was the purpose of suggesting a cross-post.

Comment: We are migrating to here, and will continue to grow in this direction, since we are now under the Salesforce1 platform. @sfdcfox

Comment: @KellyJAndrews The more you know! Of course, I always welcome new challenges and opportunities, and it will be good for us salesforcers to learn more about ExactTarget, so I'll be the first to welcome ExactTarget to our community (though I'm probably not!).

Comment: @Deepak - Be sure to take a look at [this documentation](https://code.exacttarget.com/hubexchange/registering-app) to learn how to properly set up an application to integrate with ExactTarget.  This will help you when using the FuelSDK.

Comment: @sfdcfox We can say you were :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this appears to be here:

[Code@ExactTarget](https://code.exacttarget.com/question/propertydefinitionreadonlyaccess-error-creating-profile-attributes)

### Summary

> Please re-create your HubExchange app in CODE@ App Center and make
>   sure during the create wizard you specify the correct needed
>   permissions. For this functionality you will need Read and Write
>   access for the Lists and Subscribers section.

Comment: I have already given a permission to List And Subscribers  "Read" , "Write"

Comment: After given a permission read and write .I am getting the below :[StatusCode] => Error
[StatusMessage] => The CUSTOM_OBJECTS business rule must be turned on. 
[ErrorCode] => 310007

Comment: I am able to add attribute.I have 23 user list.when I am adding the subscriber into the list with attribute.21 user attribute added successfully but last two user have does not add attribute in my list.

Comment: You should mark this question as answered, and set up a different question regarding the two users not working, with some code so we can help out. Thanks!